# How to click the call drop down using selenium webdriver python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am not able to click the call dropdown using xpath or css selector and **scrape** the phone numbers.Is there any way to do so?

```
driver=set_options_driver(headless=False)
driver.get('https://www.yellowpages.ca/bus/Ontario/Maidstone/CSR-Coxon-s-Sales-Rentals-Ltd/7222758.html?what=Rajic-Holdings-Inc&where=Maidstone+ON&useContext=true')
yp_name=[k.text for k in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='merchant__info--root ']//div[@class='merchant__name']")]
yp_addr=[k.text for k in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='merchant__info--root ']//div[@class='merchant__item merchant__address merchant__address__mobile']")]
try:
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='merchant__info-content']//span[@class='ypicon ypicon-phone mlr__icon']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='mlr mlr--merchant']//span[@class='ypicon ypicon-phone mlr__icon']").click()
    yp_phone=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='mlr__item mlr__item--more mlr__item--phone mlr__item--active isActive']//span[@class='mlr__sub-text']").text
except:
    yp_phone=" "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Call** associated with the dropdown you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.yellowpages.ca/bus/Ontario/Maidstone/CSR-Coxon-s-Sales-Rentals-Ltd/7222758.html?what=Rajic-Holdings-Inc&where=Maidstone+ON&useContext=true")
  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.merchant__info--root span.ypicon.ypicon-phone.mlr__icon"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.yellowpages.ca/bus/Ontario/Maidstone/CSR-Coxon-s-Sales-Rentals-Ltd/7222758.html?what=Rajic-Holdings-Inc&where=Maidstone+ON&useContext=true")
  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='merchant__info--root ']//span[@class='ypicon ypicon-phone mlr__icon']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: yellowpages]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of click on span element, you can try to click on anchor tag as given below.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='mlr mlr--merchant']/li/a").click
```

Comment: You will get the same error that the element is not clickable